# ngModel not updating property when using asyncPipe

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ngmodel, angular-observable

I updated my app to use `Observables`. Everything works so far, except this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients | async">
  <td>{{ingredient.name}}</td>
  <td>
    <input
      type="number"
      (keyup.enter)="updateAmount(ingredient)"
      [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount"
    >
  </td>
```

For some reason `ingredient.amount` won't get updated anymore.

Do I have to treat this in special way when `async` is involved?

Answer (score 0):

The problem (not visible in the question's code) was, that the library/module which returned the Observable was emitting immutable objects.

The corresponding *read-only* error was only visible, after I removed Angular 2's [(ngModel)] syntactic sugar and added the `(ngModelChange)` event binding myself.